# How to not use a particular column when using same schema in some other docuemnt in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have e.g 2 Schemas:

```
var AppointmentSchema = new Schema({
_id : ObjectId,    
customerId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
staffId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

var SchemaA = new Schema({
_id : ObjectId,
name : String,     
Staff : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, Appointment: [AppointmentSchema] ] ,
Pending_Appointments: [AppointmentSchema],    
},{
timestamps: true
});
```

Now as you can see in SchemaA that i have Pending_Appointments that is using the AppointmentSchema and inside staff i have a ref to user and also a sub_sub document named appointment that also uses AppointmentSchema (is the syntax correct?). So my question is in Appointment i want to use the same schema but i want to exclude staffId when inserting there because i don't need the staff I cause i am already inside it. So can someone help me . And also if someone wants to point out the better way of making the scheme , you can tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example. First of all, it makes no sense that you would have something in schema but not in the value you insert.

But anyway, to solve this, you can do this simple thing. As I can see, the duplicate field staff is not required in your schema so when you are making an entry to Schema A with AppointmentSchema just ignore that field and it will work perfectly.

Comment: Damn how could i forget  that's how mongodb works :p. If you don't insert , it wont get counted.Thank you sir, actually the reason for such a schema is that when i am inserting for pending_appointments, i will insert the staffId but when there is a confirmation , i will remove that entry from pending_appointments and than put it into appointment, but i will not insert the staffId because it's not needed. Makes sense? Or is it a wrong approach

Comment: Sometimes we miss such things, not a biggie. And please don't call me sir.

Comment: It's just my way of giving respect. Btw can you answer the rest of my question(the one in reply)

Comment: Your approach seems fine but personally I am not a big fan of using reference in MongoDB, they make things complicated and slow. (You can do some research on it). Having said that you can go ahead with what you have. If you explain the use of second schema that is schema A, perhaps I'd understand the context better.